MongoServerError: location object expected, location array not in correct format
I've built a nestjs application and in one of the schemas I defined a location field as follows:
the location field
  @Prop({ type: LocationSchema, required: isRequired, index: '2dsphere' })
  public location?: Location;

the LocationShcema
@Schema()
export class Location {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  public type = 'Point';

  @Prop({ type: [Number, Number], required: true })
  public coordinates: [number, number];
}

export const LocationSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Location);

In production when requesting creation of a document it gives me this error:
MongoServerError: location object expected, location array not in correct format

I have two questions

why does this error show up?
why does it occur only in production?


You may want to follow this mongoose documentation to set up the schema.

I did follow it. my problem is that it occurs in production only so I can't be sure for which solution would work

The code you provided does not look similar. For the different behaviour between prod and non-prod, we need more debugging details to have a deeper look.

Can you tell me which key details I should look for to tell the reason for why it work in non-prod but doesn't in prod?

It is hard to conclude since there are many potential factors that might cause such an issue. You might want to start to check the deploying process to see if there is any discrepancy. Maybe you deployed a different version of code, maybe you have a different database setup...

As it has turned out there were two indexes for the location field "2d" and "2dsphere" the format of the 2dsphere index was satisified whilst the other required it to be in the array format. I removed the 2d index and it worked!
